# GPU compute parallel radix sort optimizations

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, radix-sort

I'm looking at [1] that describes a GPU parallel radix sort algorithm. They describe multiple optimizations but in section 3 where the whole algorithm is described some things elude me.

First, the counting step is done for $n$ bits by $m$ work groups using as many work items (SIMD lanes) as possible for each work group. At the end of sec. 3.1 the count arrays are summed up in global memory. Do we end up with 1 array (counting the whole input) or with $m$ count arrays, one for each work group?

Additionally, in sec. 3.2 *Scan*, do we generate a single prefix sum *offset array* or do we get $m$ offset arrays, one for each segment of the input that is handled by its respective work group?

Finally in sec. 3.3 regarding the reordering step, everything becomes very confusing with Eq. (2) $d_i=i - lo^n + o_m^n$ especially with the local offset $lo^n$. I'm failing to understand what it represents and why it needs to be subtracted from the sorted input index $i$. Also, the last 2 paragraphs of this section, with the 8 bit packing, seem very obfuscated to me, I can't bind them to the rest of the document.

I'm trying to map out an example of a single pass of the algorithm, which would be of great help, but I'm getting stuck at the reorder step.

---

1. [Introduction to GPU Radix Sort](http://www.heterogeneouscompute.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/RadixSort.pdf) Harada, Takahiro and Lee W. Howes. (2011).

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!